# Adding text to Jquery responsiveslides slider

Tags: jquery, responsive-slides

Hello Actually i'm using jquery responsiveslides from [Responsive slides](http://www.responsiveslides.com)

how can i add text for each slide like in [this](http://renascenthemes.com/demo/honest/) can some one point me in right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this.

#### HTML:

```
<ul class="rslides" id="slider">
    <li>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/mainimg1.jpg" alt=""></a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/mainimg2.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="gallerycon">
        <h1>Your Title</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting</p>
      </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS:

```
.gallerycon{
    position:absolute;
    top:30%;
    right:40%;
    z-index: 3;
    width:60%;
    height:400px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @angel that help me for getting started.